# Is there a tool to check supported devices before uploading to Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

When you upload you apk to Google Play, you get a list of devices that are supported or not.

Is there a tool which would allow me to investigate which features will make specific devices incompatible other than disabling features one by one and uploading to check for changes in the *supported* list?

Comment: You can use alpha and beta stages at Google Play.

Comment: The reason I'm looking for this is that quite often I get "Why my device is not supported?" requests from my apps community - I'm looking for a way to investigate issues like that in an efficient way without a huge overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope it will help you, using this command you can see support screens, permissions, version etc
Run this command in cmd:

> aapt dump badging myapp.apk

Comment: Thank you! Although not _exactly_ what I was looking for, this currently seems as close as one can get.

Comment: @kulvinder is there any way for checking number of devices supported by my released .apk file before uploading to playstore. I used the above command and it gives details but it does not show the reasons why it does not support many  devices which it was previously supported. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an app that will tell you before upload, but we have basically offloaded this problem by quickly writing up another app(Lets call it ProductCompatibilityTest APP) to test OUR compatibility needs and putting it on the play store. Thats how we have solved it.

Some of the things we check in this meta app are things like RAM, Android version, SD Card slot present or not etc., all of which are easy to test. And then you can auto send this data via email or appcom to your main app that you want to install.

You can also add this feature to your app itself, test the water and send yourself complete details on devices that people are using so that you know where your app is being used. Android fragmentation is a big problem and this,for us, is an easy fix since it quickly gives us data. You can then mine this data on your servers and look for patterns for what you should be looking for as a min set for compatibility(min sdk, what are the problem devices, what are causing these problems etc.,) . I personally think writing this up might be faster than looking for tools out there, although I'd love to see if there are such tools.

So if something's not working you could redirect your users to this app(before or after) and collect data. Its additional work but it gives you insights into the cause and fragmentation.

Comment: @slartbarfast  is there any way for checking number of devices supported by my released .apk file before uploading to playstore. I used the  "" aapt dump badging myapp.apk "" command and it gives details but it does not show the reasons why it does not support many devices which it was previously supported. Any help will be appreciated.